# How to build a complex query with CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new to iOS development and coming from a Java world I am completely lost on how I should go about querying a CoreData model.

I am trying to show a list of messages grouped by who they are to and then ordered by the last message and whether the message is read or not. For example on Android I would run the following sql query.

```
SELECT *, wm1.date_timestamp AS TimeSpent " +
"FROM messages wm1 " +
"JOIN ( " +
"SELECT *, MAX(date_timestamp) as dt " +
"FROM messages " +
"WHERE to_user = ?" +
" GROUP BY from_user " +
") wm2 ON wm1.from_user = wm2.from_user AND wm1.date_timestamp = wm2.dt " +
"ORDER BY wm1.is_read ASC, wm1.date_timestamp DESC
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to go about producing something similar on iOS.

Comment: The simple fact is that you can't reproduce complex queries like that with pure Core Data, and if you need to, it might not be the tool for you. NSPredicate and NSSortDescriptor will handle only some parts of it.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense, so is there a clean way of doing this on iOS? I mean gathering a summary list above would take a lot of code without a query.

Comment: Look into FMDB if you're willing to work directly with an SQLite database instead of Core Data. It would let you work the way you're used to by executing SQL queries directly. https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: It might not be possible to reproduce that exact query, but you can get pretty close: take a look at `NSFetchRequest`'s `propertiesToFetch` and `propertiesToGroupBy`, plus `NSExpression`.  Another trick is to use `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `sectionNameKeyPath` functionality to emulate the `GROUP BY` (albeit in memory rather than in SQLite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data is not a ORM.  That is confusion number one when people come over from another language.

Core Data is an object graph that *can* persist to disk and one of those ways it can persist to disk is through a database.

This is important because your question is coming at it from a database point of view.

If you need to access a specific database that is built in a specific way then Core Data is not what you should be using.

If you are starting a fresh application and are just trying to use Core Data in a way that you are comfortable then you should stop, look at it as an object graph and rebuild your model to describe the objects you want to work with.  When you do that, the queries get a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Core data, you also can query the SQLite Database directly:

http://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/SQLite-instead-of-core-data/

However, it depends on your requirements, but Core Data is state of the art. Unfortunately you have to write the needed `JOINs` and `GROUPS`... manually. This means you have to filter, sort and join a lot of Arrays.